# Google script hash_hmac() strange behaviour

Tags: php, hash, encoding, google-apps-script

I was trying to encode a tring with hash_hmac algorithm in Google Script but the output is different from what I expected.

Google Script:

```
Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, "hello", "key"));
```

Output:

/warNnV3d4FcAI0yyOFKcFtOe/MQNRoGojthLcTHQz53V9IFJaVZO3ECDqLuFi0jEbJH6YVYYrJwEiQZZSwMkg==

Php:

```
echo hash_hmac("sha512", "hello", "key");
```

ff06ab36757777815c008d32c8e14a705b4e7bf310351a06a23b612dc4c7433e7757d20525a5593b71020ea2ee162d2311b247e9855862b270122419652c0c92

What's wrong with GS? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran into this issue last week! GS base64 encodes the raw binary result of the hash. To do this in PHP, pass a truthy value for the 4th parameter of `hash_hmac()` and then call `base64_encode()` on the result:

```
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha512", "hello", "key", true));
```

Produces:

```
/warNnV3d4FcAI0yyOFKcFtOe/MQNRoGojthLcTHQz53V9IFJaVZO3ECDqLuFi0jEbJH6YVYYrJwEiQZZSwMkg==
```

The 4th parameter:

> raw_output
>
> When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase hexits.

Comment: What if the default PHP output is desired and changes should be made to the "GS" code? It should simply be explained that the first output is Base64-encoded while the second is hex-encoded.

Comment: But I need the same result I get in php in GS.

Comment: So... base64 decode the GS output, and then hex encode it.